# aligning 2 face images based on their marker points

Tags: c++, opencv, alignment, computer-vision

I am using open cv and C++. I have 2 face images which contain marker points on them. I have already found the coordinates of the marker points. Now I need to align those 2 face images based on those coordinates. The 2 images may not be necessarily of the same height, that is why I can't figure out how to start aligning them, what should be done etc.

Comment: Have you looked into the literature of epipolar geometry?

Comment: if you have 3 corresponding markers have a look at:
`cv::getAffineTransform`
http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#Mat%20getAffineTransform%28InputArray%20src,%20InputArray%20dst%29
and use `warpAffine` aferwards.

with 4 corresponding markers you can use `getPerspectiveTransform`

Comment: epipolar geometry seems to be very interesting..im looking into it right now!@Micka isnt getAffineTransform for only one image?how to I use it to transform one image with reference to the other one?

Comment: You must split faces to corresponding 3-point triangles and then warp them to other face using perspective transform.

Comment: the tutorial on http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_calib3d/py_epipolar_geometry/py_epipolar_geometry.html explains epipolar geometry. I did not quite well understand it, but according to the image shown,it will match colors which are same on both images. Does anyone has a C++ implementation of this. I want to give this a try.

Comment: @Steph getPerspectiveTransform calculates the homography that maps the image plane from one camera position to the image plane from another camera position. Object planes can perfectly be mapped, other geometry will only be approximated. For your images I would guess that the area in between the markers will be mapped quite well (not perfectly since a face is no plane), but things outside that region will be distorted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, you cannot apply the homography based alignment procedure. Why not? Because it does not fit in this use case. It was designed to align flat surfaces. Faces (3D objects) with markers at different places and depths are clearly no planar surface.

Instead, you can:

1. try to match the markers between images then interpolate the displacement field of the other pixels. Classical ways of doing it will include [moving least squares](http://faculty.cs.tamu.edu/schaefer/research/mls.pdf) interpolation or [RBF](http://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/docs/00/09/47/64/PDF/Bartoli_Zisserman_BMVC04.pdf)'s;
2. otherwise, a more "Face Processing" way of doing it would be to use the decomposition of faces images between a texture and a face model (like [AAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_appearance_model) does) and work using the decomposition of your faces in this setup.

Comment: I have been able to match the marker points between the left and front face images and obtained a transformation matrix. I then transformed the left image with that transformation matrix using warpAffine. Now I have to superimpose the left transformed face image on the front face image so it looks like that.(left transformed image: http://i.imgur.com/1k2yZTI.jpg , front image: http://i.imgur.com/xkUD6WC.jpg, result needed:http://i.imgur.com/PSY0zh8.jpg) Could you suggest ways to do that please?

Comment: Given the amount of distortion in the images, then you have no choice but option 2: remap the face images as a texture on a 3D face model, rotate that 3D model and generate the textured image that you need.

Answer (score 1):

Define "align".

Or rather, notice that there does not exist a unique warp of the face-side image that matches the overlapping parts of the frontal one - meaning that there are infinite such warps.

So you need to better specify what your goal is, and what extra information you have, in addition to the images and a few matched points on them. For example, is your camera setup calibrated? I.e do you know the focal lengths of the cameras and their relative position and poses?

Are you trying to build a texture map (e.g. a projective one) so you can plaster a "merged" face image on top of a 3d model that you already have? Then you may want to look into cylindrical or spherical maps, and build a cylindrical or spherical projection of your images from their calibrated poses.

Or are you trying to reconstruct the whole 3d shape of the head based on those 2 views? Obviously you can do this only over the small strip where the two images overlap, and they quality of the images you posted seems a little too poor for that.

Or...?

Comment: hello there!I would like to do an image registration with those 2 images. Actually there is a third image, ie, the right profile image with the same marker points as the left profile image. My final goal would be to construct a panoramic face with those 3 images. After having found the coordinates of all the marker points on the face images,I need to align the faces. And finally blend them together. But I do not know which image alignment technique would be most suitable for my images since they have got marker points. Hope I was clear enough, but if you need more information let know

Comment: "Panoramic" does not mean much - there are many different kinds of panorama :-)   I suggest you google for "face texture cylindrical mapping" or some such. Here is an example of the result you're likely to want: http://joreg.ath.cx/imago/makingof_texturing.html

Comment: Here is the panoramic face which I want to achieve http://imgur.com/1UFWlyW Can I use "face texture cylindrical mapping" on the marker points on the face to achieve the picture that is just posted?

Comment: I gave it a try but it's not working properly unfortunately. I used the standard findHomography in http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_homography/feature_homography.html and then used warpperspective. Here is the code http://pastebin.com/dHjD4zzT. Can anyone help with this please?

Comment: The example you posted ("panoramic face which I want to achieve") looks  indeed like a cylindrical projection. You cannot obtain it using a linear (homography) warp.

Comment: Yes I realised that I will not be able to use findHomography for the face. findHomography is best used with buildings etc. I am looking into cylindrical projection right now. Thanks